# Liferay DXP Service builder @BeanReference field is null

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, liferay, osgi, liferay-dxp

In my serviceImpl class I create a custom field with the @BeanReference for Dependency Injection as bellow

```
@BeanReference(type=PersistenceClass.class)
private PersistenceClass persistenceField;
```

My PersistenceClass is an interface with an Implementation : PersistenceImplClass and I create a bean in module-spring.xml

```
<bean id="com.example.persistence.PersistenceClass" class="com.exemple.persistence.impl.PersistenceImplClass">
```

I set the attribute `dependency-injector="spring"` in my service.xml

However, my persistenceField is null

Please is some body Have an idea ?